# Find null attribute with lodash

Tags: javascript, object, properties, attributes, lodash

I have an object and I need to to check if an attribute is null, but always get undefined.

```
 var obj={
  "EMPRESA": "CMIP",
  "CD_DIRECAO": "01",
  "DT_INI_DIRECAO": "1900-01-01",
  "CD_DEPT": "10",
  "DT_INI_DEPT": "1900-01-01",
  "CD_PROC": "1",
  "DT_INI_PROC": "1900-01-01",
  "DSP_PROC": "Processo 1",
  "DSR_PROC": "Processo 1",
  "DESCRICAO": null,
  "ID_PROCESSO_ARTIGO": null,
  "VALIDACAO_ARTIGO": null,
  "DT_FIM": null,
  "DT_RowId": "row_CMIP011900-01-01101900-01-0111900-01-01",
  "DESIGEMPRESA": "CMIP",
  "DSP_DIRECAO": "Disponivel",
  "DSP_DEPT": "ADM - Administracao"
};
console.log(_.find(obj,{'DT_FIM':null}));
```

I've setup a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0a6yf34b/1/

Comment: So why not just do it with JavaScript? `if (obj["DT_FIM"]===null)`

Comment: yes, it's ok, but why i get undefined. Thanks

Comment: You get `undefined` because `_.find` expects a predicate function as a second parameter, not a key-value pair to search for. Moreover, if used on an object, it will search through _the values_.

Comment: nope . that is not true

Comment: What, the fact that `_.find` expects a predicate? Because [the documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#find) seems to be in agreement with my statement.

Comment: _.find is for collection. As @epascarello pointed out, you dont have to use lodash for checking null. Just `obj["DT_FIM"]===null` should suffice.

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).some(k => obj[k] === null);`

Comment: Sorry .. Indeed find is for collections...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hole object contains null attr

```
_.chain(obj).values().includes(null).value();
```

For certain attr

```
_.isNull(obj['DT_FIM']);
```

Your varian

```
_.find(obj,{'DT_FIM':null})
```

will work for nested object like

```
var obj={
    ...
    "DT_FIM": {"DT_FIM":null},
    ...
};
```

For all null attrs

```
_.reduce(obj, function(res, val, key) {
    if (_.isNull(val)) {
        res.push(key);
    };    
    return res;
}, [])
```

For first null attr

```
_.findKey(obj, _.isNull)
```